# Java метод paint()

Tags: java

Кусок кода:

```
private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
    Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    double x = location.getX();
    double y = location.getY();
    int i1 = (int) (x);
    int i2 = (int) (x);
    Graphics g1;
    paint(g1, i1, i2);
}  

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
   g.drawRect(x, y, 340, 20);
}
```

Что должен делать код? Рисовать прямоугольник по тем координатам, что передаются в paint()

Что делает код?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень признателен за помощь

Comment: Вы объявили переменную `g1` но не инициализировали ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А вообще, говорят, что вы не должны сами вызывать метод `paint` или `paintComponent` ...вы должны работать через `repaint()`, который сам позаботиться о настройках подходящей `Graphics`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что делает код?

инициализировать переменную `g1` т.е.

```
Graphics g1 = ...;
```